# I would like to have .div containers instead of tables, how do I do that?

Tags: html, css

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/5L3ayxrs/3/

Can someone please show me how to take out the tables and replace them with div tags? I've been searching and searching and nothing I've tried has worked. Would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Can someone show me my code in .div containers cause I've been at hours at this and I can't get it to work.

```
<table align='center'>
  <tr>
    <td valign='middle'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td style='color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 1
            <br>
            <span style='display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px; background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
          <td style='color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 2
            <br>
            <span style='display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px; background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
          <td style='color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 3
            <br>
            <span style='display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px;background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style='color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 4
            <br>
            <span style='display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px; background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
          <td style='color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 5
            <br>
            <span style='display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px; background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
          <td style='color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 6
            <br>
            <span style='display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px; background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style='color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 7
            <br>
            <span style='display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px; background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
          <td style='color:#0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 8
            <br>
            <span style='display:inline-block; width: 300px; height: 24px;background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
          <td style='color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 50px;'>
            Radio 9
            <br>
            <span style='display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px;background-color:#E2AB58'></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is completely unclear. Obviously if you want to replace the tables you implemented by `div` containers, _then do so_. So what is your _real_ question here?

Comment: That's it, div containers, I need help doing that.

Comment: So all you want is to _replace_ all the `<td> / <tr> <table>` for _divs_ ? Why don't you just like.. _replace_ the _names_ ?

Comment: Can you show me please how I can do that?

Comment: `<div>your content</div>`. That's it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

Comment: Can you show me my code in .div containers cause I've been at hours at this and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, no, I do not see _what_ there is to show at all. Post your attempt and explain what your issue is. So what I called "your _real_ question" above. Without that this looks like you only want us to do your work.

Comment: These are all me attempts: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/i-did-it-complete-and-i-used-css/228098/186

Comment: I've been at it for hours and can't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, we are not going to dig through that discussion you linked above. Code is to be posted inline in your question above. There is an `edit` button, _use it_... Invest into a proper question that can be answered. Otherwise this question is to be closed.

Comment: I tried a whole bunch of different ways.

Comment: All I'm asking for is someone to show me my code in .div containers.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/4m1hcyww/

Comment: How do I do 3 rows instead of 2?

Comment: to set a fixed width

Comment: How do I do width 300px?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/jp239wgq/

Comment: How do I have 3 rows set to 300px?

Comment: ok, so now I can specify the padding per item if I want?

Comment: Thank you so much, greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do I set padding only for items 1 through 6?

And have padding for items 6 through 9 be different?

Comment: I meant 7 through 9 having different padding.

Comment: Why isn't the font Bold, and how do I fix that? https://jsfiddle.net/jp239wgq/4/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/b7pmxmhh/ even so ...you may want to watch the percentages or even change them to actual pixels

```
<style>
.col { width: 40%; float: left; color: #0059dd;line-height:1;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;padding: padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 100px; padding-right: 10%; }
.col span {display:block; width: 300px; height: 24px; background-color:#E2AB58;}
</style>
<div class="col">
  Radio 1
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="col">
  Radio 2
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="col">
  Radio 4
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="col">
  Radio 5
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="col">
  Radio 7
  <span></span>
</div>
<div class="col">
  Radio 8
  <span></span>
</div>
```